# Multiple regression with classes

Tags: r, regression, python

I'm trying to find the best solution to resolve my problem, I have multiple ID and each ID as one or more values and in some cases no value for each class and the value I'm trying to predict.

[image]

I was thinking of using a multiple regression model so that each class but I'm running into multiple problems in some cases an ID may not have a value for a class (and I don't want to replace my NaN with 0) and an ID may have a class present multiple time (like the class 3 for C). For the latter I think the easiest solution is to sum them so I can have:

[image]

But I hope to find coefficient so that I can write an equation: a1*50+a2*40+a3*32=20 / a1*14+a2*48+a3*32+a4*14 = 12

Usually I wound use [scipy.linalg](https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/cs357-s15/public/demos/06-qr-applications/Solving%20Least-Squares%20Problems.html) or [sklearn.linear_model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) but they don't work here because I have some NaN. So what is the best modelling process in that case?